# Get an set array values through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, spring, spring-mvc

This is maybe a complicated idea.

I'm working with Java and Spring, and I'm trying to fill an pre-defined array in the DOM through jQuery.

I have the following:

```
var clients = [];
<c:forEach var="client" items="${clients}">
    clients.push("${client.id} - ${client.name}"); 
</c:forEach>
```

This array is filled by the controller in that way:

```
            mv.addObject("clients", clients);
```

The problem is that in the actual scenario the clientes array is only defined and haven't any values inside them. Is there a way to get it from the "DOM" (i don't know if is correct to say DOM here) and fill it with values obtained by an ajax call to other controller method?

In the returned page (or controller response - fragment) the array looks like these:

```
        var clients = [];

        clients.push("0 - Cli1"); 

        clients.push("1 - Cli2"); 

        clients.push("2 - Cli3");
```

The method that i'm actually try to perform to fill the array has to be something like that:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/prestamos/clients/loadClients?idCliente="+idCliente,
        type: "GET",
        cache:false,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {  
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");  
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");  
        },
        success:function(response){
            //var content = response.find("#content");
            html = $.parseHTML(response);
            // here i should get the array from the $(html) returned object
            // and after that i should store the returned array as the new ${clients} object in my page
        },
        error:function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            //alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think that, since javascript will run on the client side you wont get the actual instance of the array, just the definition. Couldn't you just modify the page to send the array values?

Comment: Maybe you're right. I'm a bit new with the framework. I research about @ResponseBody to return for example, a list of elements instead of ModelAndView but i didn't find the solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution. I define the clients array as attached attribute of the window object. And after that i fill the array in that way:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/prestamos/clients/loadClients?idCliente="+idCliente,
        type: "GET",
        cache:false,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {  
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");  
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");  
        },
        success:function(response){
            //var content = response.find("#content");
            html = $.parseHTML(response);
            script = $((html)[19]).text();          
            eval(script); 
        },
        error:function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            //alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
```

html 19 have a div with the clients inside:

```
<c:forEach items="${clients}" var="client">
    window.integrantes.push("${client.id} - ${client.nombre}");
</c:forEach>
```

The solution is for an specific situation, but maybe some part of the solution could be useful for any.